# How to write database content in a csv file and download it using Python

Tags: python, csv, urllib

I need some help. I need to write into a `csv file` and download it using Python. I am explaining my code below.

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'createfile' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<label>Type File Name: </label>
<textarea rows="4" cols="100" name="file">
</textarea>
<br>
<button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

> views.py:

```
def createfile(request):
    """ In this function remote file path is included """

    if request.GET.get('file') is not None and request.GET.get('file') != '':
        file = request.GET.get('file')
        response = urllib.urlopen(file)
        lines = response.readlines()
        report = Reactor.objects.all()
        return HttpResponse(content=lines, content_type="text/html")
    else:
        return render(request, 'plant/home.html', {'count': 1})
```

Reactor:

```
id      name        status

 1      Reactor1      1

 2      Reactor2      0
```

Here user is providing the file name and using this file the avobe database  content will be written in a csv file. finally this file will be downloaded.

Comment: So, what do you want to do? Do you want to export "Reactor" output to csv file?

Comment: @VadymStupakov : Yes I need exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

txt = """id      name        status

1      Reactor1      1

2      Reactor2      0
"""

def write_to_csv(file_name, input_str):
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=["id", "name", "status"], delimiter=';')
        writer.writeheader()

        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        for line in input_str.splitlines():
            lines = line.split()
            if len(lines) != 3:
                continue
            _id, name, status = lines
            if _id == "id":
                continue

            writer.writerow([_id, name, status])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_to_csv('csv_test.csv', txt)
```